# Group Attributes adding and deletion in Jfrog 7.25.6

Tags: attributes, artifactory

We are trying to integrate SSO with OKTA and Jfrog and got succeeded.

We tried group attributes from OKTA to Jfrog and its working, as we setup same group name in both OKTA and Jfrog and how ever we add in OKTA can be logged in to Jfrog.

Reverse process is working, i.e when we delete an user in OKTA or change a specific user from a group in OKTA, permissions are reflecting in Jfrog, but the users are not visible in that specific group?

Can you help me to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The JFrog Platform supports [SCIM](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/scim/#what-is-scim-for) (System for Cross-domain Identity Management) exactly for this purpose.

Please refer to the [SCIM documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/SCIM) in JFrog's wiki for instructions on how to set it up.